# Java: FileChannel MappedByteBuffer to UTF8

Tags: java

```
file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
channel = file.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
buffer.load();  
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++)
{
       System.out.print((char) buffer.getChar());
}
```

However this spits out non UTF8 chars. I know I'm missing something small here!

Comment: You should be using CharBuffer or a CharsetDecoder, but there is no actual question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there is some confusion in your terminology here (I think).  Java characters are UTF-16 not UTF-8.  You would not *expect* to see UTF-8 characters in a `char`.  (In fact, UTF-8 uses between 1 and 5 `bytes` to encode a single Unicode code-point.  In many cases a UTF-8 encoding of a character won't fit in a `char` ...)

This terminological confusion means that I can't be sure what you are actually trying to do, or what you are actually seeing.  So I'm going to *guess* that you are actually trying to read a file that (you believe) is encoded in UTF-8 ... or maybe in an 7 or 8-bit encoding like ASCII or Latin-1.

In that case, the main problem is that the `getChar()` method is not doing what you expect.

Your code seems to assume that `getChar` is going to (somehow) take care of decoding 
"the next character" from the bytes in the buffer.  In fact, what it does is to take the next two bytes in the buffer ... what ever they are ... combine them (using a bit-wise 'shift' and an 'or') and return them as a `char`.  The result won't bear much resemblance to the characters in the original file.  Indeed, you are likely to get a random sequence of Unicode characters, with occasional "stuff" that is no-printing, or even illegal.  (Some `char` values are reserved in and either cannot be used, or have to be used in the correct order.)

A second problem is that your loop is going to attempt to "read" more characters than there are in the buffer.  The `limit()` method returns a byte count, not a character count.

My advice is essentially the same as EJP's.  For text, use a `CharBuffer` or `CharsetDecoder`.